# What is the best way to change p5.js canvas dynamically in the same webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing, p5.js

**I'm trying to develop a webpage that allows me to change the p5.js canvas and also the slider disposition with just selecting an option from an input.**

The idea is that whenever I change the selected animation, the web page displays another skecth that is defined in the html `<head>` in this particular case:

sketch and sketch 4 are the ones that are working.

I also need to change the sliders disposition because
It depends on the sketch the different sliders that will be displayed.

Now . **I think of two ways of doing this**.

**The first one** is to change the
src atributte using another javascript file (sketchselector.js). This is not working. It changes the src but the page wont reload to load that other sketch.

**The second one** is to defined every sketch as an object using *instance mode* and I should only make that when ever it changes the option it changes the object. The problem with instance mode is that if I want to make a lot of animations I'm going to have to use it everytime and it makes my code hard to understand.

I guess that there may be A LOT of ways of doing it

therefore i want to know the best suggested way to it.

I look forward to hearing from you people.

Here is the code i´ve been tryng to make it work.

### HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Julito web page</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        
        
        <!-- P5.js !!!! -->
        <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        
        
        <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript" id='skecthselect'></script> 
        <script src="sketch4.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <!--<script src="sketch5.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

        
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    </head>
  
  
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid"  >
            <div class="col-md-1 " style="background-color:blue"> </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-10 maincontent_jp" > 
                <div class="row header_jp" >
                
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 headertext_jp">
                        <h1 class="text-center"> Juli </h1>
                        <h3 class="text-center"> Multimedia explorer</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-1 "></div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-10" id="sketchholder">
                    
                    
                        <div class="row" id="canvasholder" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="controladores" >
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                            
                                <div class="col-md-6" id="slid-controladores"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6" id="slid-texto"></div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
                </div>
                
                <select id='selector' onchange="ChangeSketch()" name="skecthselector" >
                                  <option value="skecth1.js">Animacion 1</option>
                                  <option value="skecth2.js">Animacion 2</option>
                                  <option value="skecth3.js">Animacion 3</option>
                                  <option value="skecth4.js">Animacion 4</option>
                </select>
                <p id='koko'> </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-1 " > </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="sketchselector.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

### SKETCH 1

```
       //THIS IS A FUNCTION FOR DINAMYCALLY MAKE CANVAS FILL PAGE. 
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        
            var c=document.getElementById("cnv");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        });
    
    var RectOrEllipse = false;
    var boton ; 
    var cont = 0; 
    var pepito ; 
    var RedP;
    var GreenP;
    var BlueP;
    var OpacityP;
    var SizeP;
    var maxwidth;
    var canvheight = 500;
    
      function setup () {
          
      //CREATING THE CANVAS 
    maxwidth = document.getElementById('canvasholder').offsetWidth;
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasholder');
    var sketchCanvas = createCanvas(maxwidth/1.2,canvheight);
    console.log(sketchCanvas);
    sketchCanvas.parent("canvasholder");
    
    slidred = createSlider(1,255,150);
    slidgreen = createSlider(1,255,150);
    slidblue = createSlider(1,255,150);
    slidopacity = createSlider(0,100,50);
    slidsize = createSlider(1,300,150);
    
    slidred.parent('slid-controladores');
    slidgreen.parent('slid-controladores');
    slidblue.parent('slid-controladores');
    slidopacity.parent('slid-controladores');
    slidsize.parent('slid-controladores');
    
    RedP = createP('Rojo:'+slidred.value());
    GreenP = createP('Verde: '+slidgreen.value());
    BlueP = createP('Azul: '+slidblue.value());
    OpacityP = createP('Opacidad:'+slidopacity.value())
    SizeP = createP('Tamaño: '+slidsize.value());
    pepe = createP('X'+ mouseX + 'Y' + mouseY);
    
    RedP.parent('slid-texto');
    GreenP.parent('slid-texto'); 
    BlueP.parent('slid-texto');
    OpacityP.parent('slid-texto');
    SizeP.parent('slid-texto');
    
  }

  function draw() {
    maxwidth = document.getElementById('canvasholder').offsetWidth;
    
   noStroke();
   
    
    col = color(slidred.value(),slidgreen.value(),slidblue.value(),slidopacity.value());
    fill(slidred.value(),slidgreen.value(),slidblue.value(),slidopacity.value());
    //boton.style("background-color", col);
    
    if ((mouseIsPressed) && (mouseY < canvheight)){
        
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, slidsize.value(),slidsize.value());
    }
    
    slidred.input(Actualizar);
    slidgreen.input(Actualizar);
    slidblue.input(Actualizar);
    slidopacity.input(Actualizar);
    slidsize.input(Actualizar);
    pepe.html('X'+ mouseX + 'Y' + mouseY + 'MAX WIDTH' + maxwidth);
  }
  
  function Actualizar() {
  
    RedP.html('Rojo:'+slidred.value());
    GreenP.html('Verde: '+slidgreen.value());
    BlueP.html('Azul: '+slidblue.value());
    OpacityP.html('Opacidad:'+slidopacity.value());
    SizeP.html('Tamaño: '+slidsize.value());
    
  }
  
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

});
```

### SKETCH 2

```
var ball = {
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    xspeed:0.5,
    yspeed:-0.2,
    
    display: function(tamaño) {
        stroke(1);
        strokeWeight(1);
        noFill();
        ellipse(this.x,this.y,tamaño,tamaño);
    },
    
    bounce: function() {
        if (this.x > width || this.x < 0){
            this.xspeed = this.xspeed * -1;
        }
        if (this.y > height || this.y < 0){
            this.yspeed = this.yspeed * -1;
        }
    },
    
    move: function () {
    
    /*ball.xspeed = velocidad;
    ball.yspeed = velocidad;*/
    
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed;
    },
    
    createBall : function (){
        this.display();
        this.move();
       this.bounce();
    }
}
var i;  
function setup() {
    var sketchCanvas = createCanvas(300,300);
    sketchCanvas.parent("canvasholder");
}

function draw() {
    background('#F0F');
    
    //ball.createBall();
        ball.display(50);
        ball.move();
        ball.bounce();
}
```

ADDED:

Well I´ve tryed this one in INSTANCE MODE and is not working either.

I defined two sketches in a single javascript file. when I call them they work just fine. The problem is when I want to select one over the other. That´s not working.

Here the added code:

```
function ChangeSketch() {
lala = document.getElementById('selector').value;
document.getElementById('koko').innerHTML = lala;  




/*new p5(sketch1, 'canv2');
    new p5(sketch1, 'canv1');*/
    
    function setup(){
    createP('TENGO MIEDO');
    new p5(sketch2);
    new p5(sketch1);
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two JavaScript files:

**one.js**

```
function printOne(){
    console.log("one");
    setTimeout(printOne, 1000);
}

printOne();
```

**two.js**

```
function printTwo(){
    console.log("two");
    setTimeout(printTwo, 1000);
}

printTwo();
```

And you load the first one in **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script id="MyJavaScript" src="one.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you save these files and then open `index.html` in a web browser, you'll see `one` printing to the console over and over.

Now we want to be able to change the JavaScript from `one.js` to `two.js`. So let's add a `button` to the `body` of our html:

```
<button onclick="changeMyJavaScript()">Click</button>
```

And we might try to change it by simply changing the `src` attribute of our `script` tag:

```
function changeMyJavaScript(){
   var script = document.getElementById("MyJavaScript");
   console.log("old: " + script.src);
   script.src = "two.js";       
   console.log("new: " + script.src);
}
```

We might think this works, but `one` just keeps being printed to the console! And if we try to call `printTwo()` manually, we'll get an error saying that it's not defined.

**Simply changing the `src` attribute of a `script` tag does not run that new `src`.**

However, we can instead **create a new `script` tag and add it to the DOM**:

```
function changeMyJavaScript(){
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = "two.js"; 
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
}
```

Now we'll see `two` start printing out to the console. However, we still have a problem: `one` continues to print out to the console as well. And this makes sense. We haven't actually told our code to **stop** printing `one`. Note that removing the `script` tag from the DOM does not do anything. Also note that if we click our button multiple times, we'll see `two` printed to the console more and more often.

How you handle that really depends on your code and p5.js. I'm not sure if p5.js offers a "stop running my code" function, but I doubt it. You're probably going to have to create your own stopping functions and then call them before activating a new script.

If I were you I would just keep all of my code in a single sketch and switch between it in Processing code. You could also split your Processing sketch up into multiple JavaScript files and load them all at the beginning, but still do all of the switching in Processing.

Comment: Im going to try to make all out of functions in the main program. I still have not discovered a way to do it out of functions. But I will post it here when I´ve doned it.

Comment: I´ve doned it. I created each animation as an object. And then Im using a Select html element to get the option value. 

With the option value I tell the program wich object to display in the draw function

Comment: @Julián Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, and this thread inspired me to solve it this way:

sketch.js:

```
   var x, y;
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
    }

 function draw() {
      if(mouseIsPressed) {
        drawing1();
      } else {
        drawing2();
      }
    }
```

drawing1.js:

```
function drawing1() {
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 100, 100);
}
```

drawing2.js:

```
function drawing2() {
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

and then in my index.html, just include `<script>` tags for drawing1.js and drawing2.js before the tag for sketch.js.  I just tried this now and it worked fine - a great way to break up a large p5js project into smaller pieces.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, you can check out the [p5.js overview](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview)
and the [instantiation/namespace](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace) section in particular.

Using the concepts presented there you should be able to create two sketches with two difference namespaces and containers and using `loop()`/`noLoop()` pause and resume each one as needed

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/download/) to put processing  into my web projects, and I wanted to cycle through different sketches. Processing.js has a Processing.reload() function, which makes this really easy.

```
var sketches = ["sketchname1", "example", "test"];
function nextSketch(){
            var currentLoc = $.inArray($('#canvas').attr('name'), sketches);
            currentLoc ++;
            if(currentLoc >= sketches.length){
              currentLoc = 0;
            }
            var htmlStr = '<canvas id="canvas" name="' + sketches[currentLoc] + '" data-processing-sources="' + sketches[currentLoc] + '.pde"></canvas>';
            console.log(htmlStr);
    $('#canvas').replaceWith(htmlStr);
    Processing.reload();
}
```

This was the code I used to swap between sketches. The relevant parts of my HTML looked a bit like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" name="shape" data-processing-sources="sketch1.pde"></canvas>
<button class="btn" onclick="nextSketch();"></button>
```